# Multiple losses for multi-output regression problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

So I am trying to train a CNN model to predict 4 real-valued outputs (regression problem), I tried using a Mean Squared Error as a loss function, My question is if I branch the output layer into 4 different output layers with 4 different losses(4 MSE) does this make the network performs better regarding that the weights for the last layers are updated separately.
Thank you

Comment: To understand it correctly. You have 4 values you want to predict. So the output of the last layer of your network (before the regression) has the size of 4. And this output of 4 values you want to split somehow or where do you want to split?

Comment: To be clear I have 2 Conv layers 1 Pooling layer and 2 FCN layers and one output layer, now I am thinking of using 4 output layers to compute 4 losses

Comment: What exactly is the output layer for you? Just so we talk about the same thing. Is it the output layer some layer which has some parameters that should be learned (some kind of weights) or just a layer which takes the output from the last FCN and computes 4 real values out of them.  So e.g. like in https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-neural-networks-for-regression-problems-81321897ca33 "Second : Make the Deep Neural Network", where the output layer is a FCN with 1 neuron.

Comment: Yes, it is the same as defined in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You said it is the same as in the link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-neural-networks-for-regression-problems-81321897ca33

So you have something similar to this

```
# The Output Layer :
NN_model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))
```

A FCN with 4 neurones and thus 4 outputs. So your question was if you could instead have 4 output layers. So instead of one layer with 4 neuron you will have 4 layers with one, all in parallel connected to the last FCN layer of the backbone network.

First of all it doesn't change the network architecture.
Best to look at this [image](https://missinglink.ai/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/networkgraph.png). You see that every neurons in the last layer is connected to all neurones in the second last. So by splitting the layer up into multiple layers you don't really change the architecture in any way. You still have 4 single neurons connected to all previous ones.

What it will do is change the loss. Instead of calculating the MSE over all outputs, over all batches, you will not calculate the MSE over one output over all batches 4 times. During back propagation the 4 individual gradients, from the 4 layers will be added up. So something like this will happen.

```
loss_split = mse(output1) + mse(output2) + mse(output3) +mse(output4)
```

This will compare to the loss with the 4 neuron layer the following

```
loss = loss_split / num_outputs
```

In the end this means you change the magnitude of the gradient but not the direction. Instead you could just change the learning rate or multiply the `loss` by `num_outputs`.

All in all it will make no sense in splitting the output layer into four in this case. It has no effect on the overall architecture and just complicates the network and introduces unnecessary overhead.

Btw if you really want to change things up regarding the loss and gradients you could try to use a different loss like Smooth-L1 loss. It can be more robust and perform better depending on your data.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but the weights of the last layers of the splitted losses would be different regarding that we are minimizing the loss of each output separately.

Comment: It is really hard to explain but the information flow is the same. Splitting doesn't make a difference and the gradients will take the same path back through the network. The only thing that changes is the loss values as described, but this won't make the problem any easier or harder, since it only changes the magnitude of the gradient not the direction. Something that can be achieved easier if you want. Maybe read up on how optimization works and how the gradient is calculated and flows through the network. I have a hard time explaining this, especially via text.

Comment: @Nopileos May I kindly draw your attention to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305465/how-can-plot-loss-curves-for-training-and-test-for-multi-output-regression-task).