# Tensorflow return error for each output value

Tags: tensorflow

I have a neural network (regression) with 3 output values. During training, I get a single RMSE value indicating the performance of the predictions on the test data. Is there a way that I can get the error per output value for the test data instead? That is, I get 3 RMSE values, one for each output.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=root_mean_squared_error)

def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: I think you need to create 3 different layers connected parallel to the last but one layer i.e. `tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu").` Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940812/multiple-losses-for-multi-output-regression-problem could help.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using functional API. Let say we want to get two different outputs and the output is a continuous one(Regression problem) with target variables as target1, target2. Then model can be built as:

```
Example:

def build_model():
   input_layer =  keras.Input(shape=(train.shape[1],))
   dense1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_layer)
   dense2 = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(dense1)
   # first output is fed from dense1(target1 variable)
   output1 = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", name="target1")(dense2)

   dense3 = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(dense1) # getting the 
   # second output is fed from dense3(target2 variable)
  output2 = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", name="target2")(dense3)

   # Define the model with input layer and a list of output layers.

   model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output1, output2])

   return model

   # Now compile the model
   # specify the optimizer

   model.compile(
            optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),
            loss = {"target1":"mse", "target2":"mse"},
            metrics={'target1':tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(),
          'target2':tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()},
               )
```

Now , the Y-data or the target data must be a tuple or a list containing Y1,Y2 where Y1 and Y2 are numpy 1D-arrays.

```
    # fit the model.
    # Train the model for 10 epochs
    history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y,
    epochs=100, batch_size=10, validation_data=(validation_X, validation_Y))
```

The loss "mse" and the metric "rmse" will be seen during training.

The prediction is calculated as:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(test_X)
target1_pred = Y_pred[0]
target2_pred = Y_pred[1]
```